# Parse a list to a string

Tags: c#, string, list, foreach

Maybe I'm being too clever, but I have a method that goes through a enumerable List(Collections) and returns it as an ........... enumerable List(Sparkles).

I wanted to enclose the first list(Collections) in a class that handles validation and various other duties, otherwise I'd handle directly with the Collections.

I'm pretty sure that sounds more difficult that I should of made it. So the class returns a list(Sparkles) through a method called *getSparkles()*.

I thought I was do a foreach right:

```
string msg;
List<string> layoutListNames = new List<string>();

foreach (string name in layoutList.getLayout());
{
     msg = "\n" + name;
}
```

The compiler, however, disagrees with me.

Give me a hint. I would like to learn.

Edit: Sorry. getLayout() returns a List<>. And I removed the semicolon.
Oh /facepalm.

I wrote this in a constructor to test a class and forgot to change the name of the constructor to match the class name. Thanks for the incredibly fast responses.

Comment: "The compiler, however, disagrees with me" - could you be a little more specific...

Comment: what does `layoutList.getLayout()` return?  and without knowing exactly what sort of disagreement you are having with the compiler it's a little difficult to help...

Comment: Waht does the compiler complain about? How is layoutlist.getLayout() defined?

Comment: What is `layoutList`, what is the `getLayout` method? How does the compiler 'disagree' with you (error message)?

Comment: in addition to the above comments, `foreach (string name in layoutList.getLayout()) ;` what's the semicolon doing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whats wrong is the ';' behind 
    foreach (string name in layoutList.getLayout()) ;

Remove that, and the compiler agrees..

Suggestion for making it better:

```
string msg = string.Join("\n", layoutListNames);
```

Comment: I'll go with this answer. Never knew about the String.Join method.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing: You need to remove the `;` after the `foreach`. Otherwise this will be an empty loop statement and in the following block `name` will not be declared.

Answer (score 1):

and try it again...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string msg = null;
        List<string> layoutListNames = new List<string>() { "test1","test2"};

        foreach (string name in layoutListNames)
        {
            if (msg != null) msg += "\n";
            msg += name;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("at 1:" + msg);

        msg = string.Join("\n", layoutListNames.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine("at 2:" + msg);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: again, still contains the erroneous `;` at the end of the foreach, and thus won't compile.